# how to combine two arrays with the same array key then if the value is the same then it is not displayed and if it is different it will be displayed

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arraylist

I have been fighting with this all day and would like another set of eyes to maybe give me some insight. I'm not sure I am even approaching this the correct way. I have two arrays but these arrays have different number lists. I'm building an app with Laravel.

```
$naflr = array(
    0 => "NA"
    1 => "A2"
    2 => "A2"
    3 => "A1"
    4 => "A1"
    5 => "A1"
    ...
    49 =>"A3"
)

$fuzifikasi = array(
    0 => "A2"
    1 => "A1"
    2 => "A4"
    3 => "A1"
    4 => "A1"
    5 => "A1"
    ...
    48 => "A4"
)
```

How do I filter the value array from the NAFLR array with `FUZIFIKASI`, I hope the result is like this

```
$resul = array(
    [na] = array(
        0 => "A2"
    )

    [A2] = array(
        0 = > "A1"
        1 => "A4"
    )
    ....
)
```

Comment: What is the question @salman. Do you want to loop over `$naflr `,  get the key and value of each item in that array (say value is `$v` and the key is  `$k`). Then get the value (say `$v2`) from array  `$fuzifikasi `  that corresponds to the key `$k` and assign this value to another array (say `$r`) with key as `$v` and value as `$v2`. Is this what you need?

Comment: I want to create a group from an array of $naflr values, which contains the value of $fuzzification the benchmark for example if $naflr has value A2 on row 1 then the value of $fuzzification is put into group A2

Comment: _$naflr has value A2 on row 1 then the value of $fuzzification is put into group_ -> which value from `$fuzzification`

Comment: Yes, Can you provide a sample code??

Comment: I was asking which value from the array `$fuzzification` need to put into the group `A2`

Comment: Value whose array key is equal to $naflr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your description correctly, then all you need to do is loop over your first array, check if an item with the same index exists in your second array (not clear from your explanation, whether those will always have the exact same number of items or not), and if so, add it to the result array using the value from the first array as key:

```
$result = [];

foreach($naflr as $index => $value) {
    if(isset($fuzifikasi[$index])) {
        $result[$value][] = $fuzifikasi[$index];
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/L34El

Comment: May I ask another question sir?

Comment: Regarding this specific problem, or something else? If the latter, then you should create a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68417882/how-to-add-multidimensional-array-values-whose-values-are-from-different-array    @CBroe I write here, I hope you will help me again :)