# how to add multidimensional array values ​whose values ​are from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, array-sum

I have been fighting with this all day and would like another set of eyes to maybe give me some insight. I'm not sure I am even approaching this the correct way. I have two arrays, namely a multidimensional array and a single array, I am trying to add up the contents of a multidimensional array whose values ​​are taken from a single array, where the contents of the multidimensional array are the same as the array keys of a single array. I'm building an app with Laravel.

```
$multidimensionArray = array:6 [▼
  "A2" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "A1"
    1 => "A2"
    2 => "A3"
  ]
  "A1" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "A1"
    1 => "A6"
    2 => "A5"
    3 => "A2"
  ]
  "A6" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "A3"
  ]
  "A3" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "A3"
    1 => "A2"
  ]
  "A5" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "A4"
  ]
  "A4" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "A4"
    1 => "A3"
  ]
]

$singeArray = array:6 [▼
  "A1" => 675.58333333333
  "A2" => 1786.75
  "A3" => 2897.9166666667
  "A4" => 4009.0833333333
  "A5" => 5120.25
  "A6" => 6231.4166666667
]
```

how to add the value in $multidimensionalArray according to the key whose value is taken from $singleArray, then divided by the number of keys in $multidimensionalArray, for example: in key "A2" in multidimensionalArray has values ​​A1,A2,A3 and in singleArray the values ​​of A1,A2,A3 are 675.58333333333, 1786.75, 2897.9166666667, how to add them then divide by 3(according to the number of values ​​in A2).

I hope the result is like this

```
$result = array(
"A2" => 1786.75
"A1" => 3453.5
...etc

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `foreach` and `array_filter`.

Since you want average of the values it can be done with `array_sum`.

This should work

```php
$results = [];
foreach ($multidimensionArray as $key => $valueArr) {
    ## filter out all values of interest from $singleArray
    $filteredValues = array_filter($singeArray, function ($value, $identifier) use ($valueArr) {
        return in_array($identifier, $valueArr);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
    ## Here we get the average
    $results[$key] = array_sum($filteredValues) / count($filteredValues);
}
print_r($results);
```

[Working sandbox link](https://3v4l.org/PFnKO)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$result = [];

array_walk($multidimensionArray, function($value, $key) use(&$result, $singeArray) {
   // get only those items from $singeArray which exist in $value
   // sum and divide by 3
   $result[ $key ]  = array_sum( array_intersect_key( $singeArray, array_flip($value) ) ) / 3;
});

var_dump( $result );
```

Edit:
Updated my answer forgot to use `array_flip`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 2d array's row values are unique, the most efficient way to filter the data is to filter the 1d array by a flipped version of the targeted row's data -- this will be much less expensive that making iterated `in_array()` calls.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/GgQ0T)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($multi as $key => $row) {
    $values = array_intersect_key($single, array_flip($row));
    $result[$key] = array_sum($values) / count($values);
}
var_export($result);
```